# Capitalize hyphenated names in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to capitalize names in javascript and so far I've found these methods on SO:

```
// doesn't capitalize first letter after hyphen -> gives Bjørn-martin
str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt) { return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase(); });

// capitalizes after hyphen, but also after funny Norwegian characters (æøå) -> gives BjøRn-Martin
str.replace(/\b[\w']+\b/g, function (txt) { return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase(); });

// same as first
str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/^[\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w]|\s[\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w]/g, function(letter) {
    return letter.toUpperCase();
});
```

When trying to capitalize `bjørn-martin` none of them handles both funny Norwegian characters and hyphen.

I'm not exactly well versed in regex and was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction so that `bjørn-martin` is correctly capitalized to `Bjørn-Martin`.

Comment: Do you consider using [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should suit your needs:

```
var capitalized = input.replace(/(^|[\s-])\S/g, function (match) {
    return match.toUpperCase();
});
```

Comment: This will not work in all possible situations. You should add the assumptions to the answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I believe it handles *both funny Norwegian characters and hyphen* as the OP asks, unless I'm missing edge cases?

Comment: I found a case where it won't work. 'james bond' gives 'James bond'. I didn't mention it in the question, but I thought it was obvious that not only the first name should be capitalized :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a configurable method. This will allow you to specify the word separators.

Pattern you need: `/(^|-)(\w)/g`

```js
function transformToUpperCase(str, separators) {
  separators = separators || [ ' ' ];
  var regex = new RegExp('(^|[' + separators.join('') + '])(\\w)', 'g');
  return str.toLowerCase().replace(regex, function(x) { return x.toUpperCase(); });
}

document.body.innerHTML = transformToUpperCase('bjørn-martin', ['-']);
```

Comment: This won't work if the name starts with the "funny" letter.

Comment: Many thanks works very well with Frencg hyphenated names