# How to convert SVG style to JSX

Tags: reactjs

I would like to know is there any inbuilt function or something in react for converting SVG style attribute to JSX.

I have style like this:

```
'opacity:0.647;fill:#cbcbcb;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#cbcbcb;stroke-width:0.26458335;stroke-opacity:1'
```

I want to convert it into:

```
{{"opacity":"0.647","fill":"#cbcbcb","fillOpacity":"1","stroke":"#cbcbcb","strokeWidth":"0.26458335","strokeOpacity":"1"}}
```

Is there any easy way?

Comment: split at `;`, split every pair at `:`. Split the key of every pair at `-`, capitalize and join. Now collect the result into an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in functionality for this. You may convert your styles string into an object using a simple reducer function, and then pass it as a prop.

```js
const str =
  "opacity:0.647;fill:#cbcbcb;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#cbcbcb;stroke-width:0.26458335;stroke-opacity:1";

const styles = str.split(";");
const svgStyles = styles.reduce((obj, item, i) => {
  const [key, value] = item.split(":");
  const updatedkey = key.replace(/-([a-z])/ig, s => s.slice(-1).toUpperCase());
  obj[updatedkey] = value;
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(svgStyles);
```

Comment: yeah... this one is good... but I thinks this function is not removing hyphen and capitalize...  thank you

Comment: Then you may also make use of a helper function to turn them also to Capitalized: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504848/capitalize-hyphenated-names-in-javascript

Comment: I worked on it and updated your answer, thanks for your help...

Comment: Approved it. You may now mark it as selected answer.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure there exists a React inbuilt tool for this. You could code this yourself and make your own quick tool to transform the syntax. Othwerise, if you don't want to use external websites, you can have a look at the svg-to-jsx module which can be used within your project or via command line

```
npm install svg-to-jsx
```

or svgr (https://github.com/gregberge/svgr) for SVG -> React component directly if you prefer

Comment: this module is need all SVG to convert JSX, right...? is this convert only the style?

Answer (score 0):

There's a vscode extension for this called **"html to JSX"**

Here's the link to the extension:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=riazxrazor.html-to-jsx

Just select all of your svg code and then press Ctrl + Shift + P -> Convert HTML to JSX